# Wait for observable to complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have series of methods which are dependent on completion of other methods.

```
process1(data: string) : Observable<string> {
   this.dataservice.process(data).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                return response.data;
            }
        );
}

main(data: string) : string {

   var process1Data: string = process1(data); 

   // I would like to wait for process1 method to complete before running process2
   // I do not want to include process2 inside subscribe of process1 because I have to make few more method calls
   var process2Data: string = process2(process1Data);

   var process3Data: string = process3(process2Data);

   ...

}
```

How can I wait for an observable to complete before calling next method (process2, process3)? (similar like await in c#)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might try something like this...

```
main(data: string) : string {

    process1Data$: Observable<string> = process1(data)
        .take(1)
        .switchMap((process1Data) => return process2(process1Data);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Obviously, `take(1)` assumes that `process1(...)` resolves to single value and stops. After that it `switchMap`s to `process2` which means it starts emitting whatever observable from `process2` gives.
If, on the other hand, you want `process2` to be ran of each result emitted from `process1` then just remove `take(1)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use rxjs concat operator. 
See documentation here. 
[concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html)

Basically it waits untill the first or source observable returns and then executes next.

**update**

You can also try operators like switch or switchmap according to your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use es6 async/await

```
async main(data: string): string {
    var process1Data: string = await process1(data).toPromise();
    var process2Data: string = process2(process1Data);
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes, it would work this way however I will have to make all main's calling methods async too. Is it possible to implement this without making main async? I am ok to make process1 async if required.

Comment: @Andre that's inaccurate, Observables are interoperable with Promises - see [RxJS Observable interop with Promises and Async-Await](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875)

Answer (score 0):

`process1` in the original question is confusing as it does not return an `Observable<string>` (Maybe I'm using another `Observable` from 'rxjs/Observable').

This is the code I'm referring to (in original question):

```
process1(data: string) : Observable<string> {
   this.dataservice.process(data).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                return response.data;
            }
        );
}
```

For me, I changed it to this:

```
process1(data: string) : Observable<string> {
   return this.dataservice.process(data).map(  //subscribe-->map
            (response) => {
                return response.data;
            }
        );
}
```

Then to have something happen after `process1` completes, just use `subscribe` like you would with any other `Observable`:

```
main(data: string) : string {
   process1(data).subscribe((process1RetVal)=>
   {
         process2(process1RetVal);
   });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need is the concatMap operator.

Every item that is emitted through the concatMap operator will be executed one by one. You can leverage this to achieve what you want.

Comment: although this may be a valid pointer, if you want your answer to be useful please explain and give code examples on how to solve it, otherwise the answer is not really useful to most.

Comment: i was not aware that it is required to give full solutions?